# Prevent image wrap (move) around on browser resize

Tags: css, css-float, positioning

On my main page, I have an image that moves around or wraps around on browser resize. I just want to change it so that the image gets cut from the right if the browser is small.

I have tried a few things to no avail:

1. Remove the float on the div id `right` and the relative positioning on `right-image`
2. Try min-width for div id `right`
3. Give height, widths in percentages
4. Added viewport settings.

In the template, the image is placed outside the `main` like:

```
<body>
    <div id = "main"> 
        <div id = "left">
            <div id="left-title">Tag Line</div>
            <div id="left-blurb">
                 Some blurb
            </div>
        <div id='left-signup'> SignUp! button</div>
    </div>

    <div id = "right">
        <div id = "right-image"></div>     <--- Image
    </div>

</body>
```

Relevant css:

```
body    {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#main   {
    float: center;
    width: 950px;
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#left-title {
    font-size: 3.4em;
    margin: 25px 0px 20px 15px;
}
#left-blurb {
    margin: 0px 20px 10px 15px;
}
#left-signup {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 90px;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#right-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative; 
    left: -50px; 
    top: 0px; 
    background: url(my_photo.jpg) no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

I think that is the css that is relevant to the question. But if it is not enough, the website I am talking about is https://www.mathnuggets.com

Will appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a media query to just remove it from the document when your document size is less than a certain number of pixels.

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    #right-image{
       display: none;
     }
}
```

Otherwise, you can also adjust its positioning as you've done using the same method, just adjusting its position depending on window size. The issue I'm seeing in your code is that you're using a -10px margin that is causing it to overlap your other elements, so you could simply change that for certain viewport sizes.

In addition, you might want to consider changing your sizing method from being absolute using pixels and instead use percentages so that your image can flex a little as your viewport changes.

This site has a lot of great resources I think could help you to work with your existing design so that it can be more responsive as needed: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design

Comment: You're welcome, I'm sorry if I didn't really quite understand the spirit of your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
position: absolute;
```

for ID=right div it will never go under left div

Comment: I thought this worked at first, but this messes up the layout on different browsers. And specifying margins doesn't fix it.

Comment: The CSS pasted in the question is the relevant part of code, I think. What other CSS would help? I can post it. If you may, you could also check it at https://www.mathnuggets.com